# Is there 2 factor authentication for Google Apps Mail (i.e. not gmail)?

Tags: google-workspace

I'm talking about the Google Apps Mail for companies.  Does two factor authentication exist for that product?

Comment: It does, just as for Gmail. But it must be turned on by the domain administrator before users can see/enable it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can have two factor authentication for Apps

[Setup instructions for your domain administrator](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=175197)

[Setup instructions for individual users](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180744)